Canonical Basis of Tangent Space of a Manifold regarding Charts

Consider the upper half of the sphere,  $\mathbb{S}^2_+:=\{p\in S^2\mid p_3>0\}\in\mathbb{R}^3$and the charts $(\mathbb{S}^2_+, x=\mathcal{i}_N), (\mathbb{S}^2_+, y=\pi_N)$ where $\mathcal{i}_N$ is the stereographic projection around N and $\pi_N$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\{p_3=0\}$, i.e. $\pi_n(p)=(p_1, p_2)$. Furthermore, I consider a path $\alpha: (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})\to\mathbb{S}^2, \alpha(t):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}\cos(t)\\\sin(t)\\1\end{array}\right)$ and $p:=\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{array}\right)$.
Write $[\alpha]\in T_p\mathbb{S}^2$ using the canonical basis regarding the charts $x, y$.

I already determined the basis vectors of $T_p\mathbb{S}^2$ regarding the charts $x, y$ as $$\partial_{x^1}(p)=\left(\begin{array}{c}-p_1^2+1-p_3\\-p_1p_2\\p_1(1-p_3) \end{array}\right), \partial_{x^2}(p)=\left(\begin{array}{c}-p_1p_2\\-p_2^2+1-p_3\\p_2(1-p_3) \end{array}\right)\\ \partial_{y^1}(p)=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\-\frac{p_1}{p_3} \end{array}\right), \partial_{y^2}(p)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\-\frac{p_2}{p_3} \end{array}\right)$$ and the Jacobian $$D(\pi_N\circ\mathcal{i}_N^{-1})(x)=\frac{1}{(\vert x\vert^2+1)^2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}-2x_1^2+2x_2^2+2 & -4x_1x_2\\-4x_1x_2 & 2x_1^2-2x_2^2+2\end{array}\right)$$
But I'm not sure how to proceed as I'm still getting used to the definitions and notations.
In the lecture we noted that if $[\alpha]=\xi^1\partial_{x^1}(p)+\xi^2\partial_{x^2}(p)$ then one can define the so called coefficient functions $\gamma^i$ by $\gamma^i(t)e_i=(x\circ\alpha)(t)$ and use them as $\xi^i=(\gamma^i)'(0)$, is that true?
Therefore for $x$ I would have $$(x\circ\alpha)(t)=x\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}\cos(t)\\\sin(t)\\1\end{array}\right)\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(t)}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\\\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(t)}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\end{array}\right)=:\gamma(t)$$ which yields $\xi^1=0,  \xi^2=1+\sqrt{2}$, is this correct or do I have to approach this in a different way?
Thank you in advance!
